# Xdebug profiler and xdebug_time_index() give different values

Tags: php, xdebug

I used Xdebug to profile my PHP application.

When I open the generated profile file with WinCacheGrind, it gives me a total cumulative time of 3ms for {main} (0.003s).

However, when I use the function xdebug_time_index() at the end of my code, it returns a time of 0.03s.

Anyone knows what might cause this difference and which one is more representative ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any chance adding that function actually increases the time needed?

Also, I can imagine the profiler will actually start running when PHP runs (time index 0) while XDebug's internal counter can start a bit earlier.